# Hide Facebook like on click

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick

For my website, I want to add a Facebook like to my website.

Here is the code I used:

```
document.write('<iframe id="like-box" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href='+ like_url +'&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:60px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');

var popupDiv = document.getElementById('like-box');
popupDiv.onclick = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    alert("Like button will be removed");
    document.removeChild(popupDiv);
};
```

Where `like_url` is a string that contains my website url.

I want the iframe to be removed when the user has clicked on it. But the above code doesn't work at all. **The onclick function is never triggered.** Is there a way to make it work properly ?

I've also tried to do the same with the twitter button like that:

```
document.write('<div id="like-box" style="left:0; top:0; width: 500px; height: 230px;">');
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
document.write('<g:plusone href="' + gplus_url + '"></g:plusone>');
document.write('</div>');

var popupDiv = document.getElementById('like-box');
popupDiv.onclick = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    alert("G+ button will be removed");
    document.removeChild(popupDiv);
};
```

But it doesn't work neither ! **I've tried to trigger the click on window** but I got the same result.

Can you help me to solve it ?

Edit:

I'll try to explain it in a better way.
I want to detect click event inside or over an iframe FROM the main document. I mean:
I'm on my website. I click on the facebook like, the click is triggerd by my index.html page, then I remove the iframe after a couple of seconds. But the like has been catched by FB.
This is basically what I want to do. I've tried many code that trigger a function when clicking on the iframe but none of them worked.
For example:

```
onload="this.contentWindow.document.onclick=function(){alert(\'test\')}"
```

Doesn't work at all.

Edit 2:
This looks to be a serious problem because if I use a onclikc function on my window (eg. `window.onclick = function(e) {...};` it's not triggered when I click in the iframe. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the way to do it (at least for the first click). If someone need the code, here it is:

```
var inIframe = false;
function checkClick()
{
    if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement === document.getElementById("iframe_id_goes_here"))
    {
        if (inIframe == false)
        {
            console.log("Clicked");
            inIframe = true;
        }
    }
    else inIframe = false;
}
setInterval(checkClick, 200);
```

Thanks for those who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `document.removeChild(popupDiv)` try this:

```
popupDiv.parentNode.removeChild(popupDiv);
```

IIRC, you can only remove nodes using their parent node, not the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

Remove from the body: `document.body.removeChild(popupDiv);`

Answer (score -2):

Try `document.getElementById(popupDiv).innerHTML = "";`

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not to remove, it's to trigger the click

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. Is there a way using `designMode="on";` or something ?